# How to enumerate files + folders recursively with System.IO.Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

How can I change this code to also enumerate sub directories?

```
var fqFilenames= new List<String>(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sMappedPath));
var filenames= fqFilenames.ConvertAll((s) => { return s.Replace(sMappedPath+"\\", ""); });
FileListView.DataSource = filenames;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Can you just use `Directory.GetFiles(string, string, SearchOption)`? If not, please explain what you need which that doesn't cover.

For example:

```
Directory.GetFiles(sMappedPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) or the DirectoryInfo equivalent.
The example on the linked page shows recursively traversing subdirectories