# Search for the path to a file in C#

Tags: c#, search

I need to access a file created at a random location in the `%temp%` directory, for example at a path like:

```
%temp%/[FSF480-3R3RC3-RDDWW-32FDF-3FD3E-]/files/test.txt
```

Can someone tell me how to search for, and return a path to 'test.txt' so I can open it to read data from it?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to extract the path without the filename from this string?

Comment: I'm extracting the files from a CAB file to the temp directory, then I need to read data from a particular file - so I need to know the location of it - the problem is the path (as above) is random in each CAB file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by using [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53zya234.aspx) for a recursive search through the directory tree and [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hwtke0f.aspx) to list the files in each.

This should allow you to find the file.

See [this walkthrough](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) on the Microsoft Support site.

Comment: I didn't downvote but wanted to ask:  Unless you need to perform an operaton on each subdirectory, is there an advantage to this approach over a `Directory.GetFiles()` with `SearchOption.AllDirectories`?

Comment: @Sugerman - it allows you to stop once a certain condition is met (say you only want the first 100 entries). It really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Oded I was asking in the context of this Question since that's what the Answer is in response to.

Comment: @Sugerman - In this context, the same applies. Once the file has been found, no need to search through more directories.

Answer (score 4):

[Directory.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571.aspx) will let you search for files that match a pattern under a specific path, optionally searching subdirectories.  The linked MSDN page shows usage.

Very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270399/how-to-enumerate-files-folders-recursively-with-system-io-directory-getfiles) where it is suggested to use `Directory.GetFiles` with the recursive option.

```
Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetTempPath(), "test.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Use `GetFiles()` if you're searching for few results, `EnumerateFiles()` if your searching for many.

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles
>   methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start
>   enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is
>   returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names
>   to be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be
>   more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

the [GetCreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcreationtime.aspx) method may additionally help u to determine the right folder after using GetDirectories (see Oded's post) - I don't know whether u have any information about the directory name, if u do, it may be good to use a combination of both of them.