# Detect path in code "/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet"

Tags: c#

I have a question can I detect this path `"/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet"` somehow in code? Is this on every machine different?
I need to start a console application with this, mz local machine is Mac and this works, but I am starting the console on windows

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet);

    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more context? Why do you need to do this? Why this specific path? Can you share any relevant code?

Comment: added @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: You'd normally expect `dotnet` to be added to your PATH, so you can invoke it using `dotnet`

Comment: @canton7 can you give an example?

Comment: @RDJT Of what? Invoking `dotnet`? `new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet")`

Comment: @canton7 ah, sorry, that was obvious,. didn't get me . Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you are working on Visul Studio you can use Ctrl + Shift + F on search add the path(is case sensitive) and on th drop down use "In all solution" and click on "Search all"

Comment: Oh i've read so bad i think that these is what you whant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838093/search-for-the-path-to-a-file-in-c-sharp