# Renaming a portion of a group of files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a list of files in a directory with this naming convention:

`CFW-500-FY13Q4.doc`

`CFW-501-FY13Q4.doc`

`CFW-502-FY13Q4.doc`

...

`CFW-520-FY13Q4.doc`

I was trying to replace the `FY13Q4` with `FY14Q1` but I’m having a hard time wrapping my head around how to rename only that portion of the files without losing the numbering sequence (500, 501, etc). This was my current code, which is not working for me since it all does is renames the first file which is `CFW-500-FY13Q4` to `CFW-500-FY14Q1.doc` and the rest go untouched.

```
Dim a As Integer = 500
For Each f As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(newDir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*CFW*")
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(f, "CFW-" & a & "-" & "FY14Q1" & ".doc")
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can just a replace method:

```
Dim a As Integer = 500
For Each f As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(newDir, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*CFW*")
My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(f, f.replace("FY13Q4", "FY14Q1"))
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, but it's throwing out this error: Argument 'newName' must be a name, and not a relative or absolute path: 'C:\Users\account1\Documents\testenvironment\FY14Q1\CFW-500-FY14Q1.doc'.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start using IO namespace, specifically IO.Directory and IO.FileInfo, since it makes your code more maintainable, as you now operate at a higher level, rather than simple strings.

See this answer by Jon Skeet:

[how to enumerate files + folders recursively with System.IO.Directory.GetFiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270414/897326)

[FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.io.fileinfo) has a [MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method, which resolves the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-off task, you can do it at the command prompt with

```
ren ????????FY13Q4.doc ????????FY14Q1.doc
```